# Angular adds a day when displaying the date (dd/MM/yyyy)

Tags: angularjs

I have a datepicker where the user picks the date without choosing the time, the date is saved correctly in my data base but when I display it, it shows one day ahaid, when I looked up the issue it turns out that it's a timezone issue that lots of people face but i didn't quite understand how to fix it in my code :

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="ft in ftListesorted">
      <td>{{ft.NomProjet}}</td>
      <td>{{ft.NomTache}}</td>
      <td>{{ft.Datefeuillestemps |  date : 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

I get the "ft.Datefeuillestemps" from my database where the default time is always set to T00:00:00.

For example here's how my date is stored in the data base : **2017-05-17 00:00:00.0000000** and this is what I get in my view : **18/05/2017** so a day is added.

How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.passdate = function (dt) {
    var targetTime = new Date(dt);
    var timeZoneFromDB = -7.00; //time zone value from database
    //get the timezone offset from local time in minutes
    var tzDifference = timeZoneFromDB * 60 + targetTime.getTimezoneOffset();
    //convert the offset to milliseconds, add to targetTime, and make a new Date
    var offsetTime = new Date(targetTime.getTime() + tzDifference * 60 * 1000);
    $scope.ISODateString(offsetTime);
}
```

check this if helps

Answer (score 1):

You could subtract (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() from your object (assuming the date in the database is on GMT), but this is not perfect. You will still have issues when timezones change differently because of daylight saving time.